# Failed to resolve packages. Failed to add editor bundled package --> Circle Ci

Tags: unity-game-engine, circleci, cicd, build-pipeline

I've been having this problem for about a week now and I don't know what to do. I always build to project with flatman. I tried everything but it didn't work. Please help.

and manifest files have these

["com.unity.buy": "4.3.0",
"com.unity.purchasing.udp": "2.0.0",][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF1cg.png

Comment: I'm having the same error in my build server setup (but not locally.) You ever solve this?